# HTML5 - Collisions

Tags: javascript, html, collision

I'm working on a top down game, and this game is going to contain a lot of collisions simple and complex.

After doing some research, I understand that I have to always compare my character with 'object' within my code - and then check for collision calculations.

EG:

```
CheckCollisions(Player, Object);
```

Which means I have to add in every single collide-able object within my scene, into my code:

```
CheckCollisions(Player, Building1);
CheckCollisions(Player, Building2);
CheckCollisions(Player, Trash);
CheckCollisions(Player, Bench1);
CheckCollisions(Player, Bench2);
CheckCollisions(Player, Office1);
CheckCollisions(Player, Office2);
```

First off, my objects might not even be simple rects, they might be complex shapes. Secondly, some of them might have their own rotation. And thirdly, what happens if I have over tens of thousands of collie-able objects in my scene?

Ins't there an easier way to check for collisions within a HTML5/JS game?

Is this even possible? I'm really just looking for some advice and pointers.

Thanks

Comment: a) use a loop b) browsers are very performant theses days c) there are better collision-detection algorithms for many objects

Comment: For the complex shapes, please be more specific. Show us your `CheckCollisions` code, and what you have tried to match these cases.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, I haven't actually coded my CheckCollisions yet as I'm researching the best method. When I say 'complex shapes', I mean a shape that has it's own polygon points (eg - to draw a star shape, etc ...)

Comment: You could check out [GameDev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) as well (be sure to read their FAQ though,  I'm not a regular there so I'm not entirely sure what their scope is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - you don't need to write a line of code for every object in your game. Put them into an array and loop over the array:

```
var collidableObjects = [Building1, Building2, Trash, Bench1, Bench2,Office1, Office2];
var CheckAllCollisions = function() {
    for (var i=0; i<collidableObjects.length; i++) {
        CheckCollisions(Player, collidableObjects[i]);
    }
}
```

2 - if you have complicated collision check (ie rotated shape, polygon, etc) you can first check a simple rectangle check (or radius check) and do the more accurate check if the first one returns true.

3 - if you plan to have tens of thousands of objects you should have smarter data collections, for example objects sorted by X coordinate so you can quickly avoid checking everything larger than Player.X+100  and smaller than Player.X-100 (using binary search),  or split the objects into a grid and just check the objects in the 3x3 grid cells around the player.

Answer (score 2):

It's very uncommon to have a named variable for every single object in your game. Usually you store all objects in one data structure (like an array) and when you need to do something with all objects, you do a for-loop over this array.

Some important objects, like the player character, could have an own variable, but they should also be in the "all objects" array, so you don't need to program a special handling to include the player character.

Regarding performance: When you check everything against everything, the amount of collision checks which need to be performed increases quadratically. But you can reduce the effort when you only check collisions of those objects which are already close to each other. Before you check collisions, you:

1. divide the playing field into rectangular zones (the zones must be at least as large as the largest object).
2. Then you assign each object to the zone its upper-left corner is in.
3. Then you take each zone, and check collisions of each object in it with the other objects in the zone and with all objects the three zones right, down and rightdown from it (for objects which overlap zone borders).

When you have very complex shapes, you could also speed up collision-detection by calculating a bounding-rectangle for each shape (the smallest possible rectangle it fits into). Before you check the collision between two objects, you first check if their bounding rectangles intersect. When they don't, there is no chance for the complex shapes to intersect, and you can skip all the complex calculations.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone so far has indicated, an array of objects is much better than naming all your objects individually.

**A much easier method of collision detection** that might work for you is to have a central object that tracks all occupied spaces. For instance, let's call it `LocationTracker` for now.

Assuming you're only using x and y axes, you can have a Point object that stores an X and a Y location, (and if you want to get fancy,  a `timestamp`). Each object as it moves would send an array of all the `Point`s that it is occupying. For example, you can call `locationTracker.occupySpace(player[i], array(point(3,4), point(4,4), point(5,4))`, etc.

If your call to `occupySpace` returns false, none of the Points match and you're safe, if it returns true, then you have a collision.

The nice thing about doing it this way is if you have x amount of objects, instead of checking x*x times per move, you check x times max.

You wouldn't need to pass in all points of the objects, just the outer most ones.

Answer (score 0):

A much better way is to put all your scene objects into an array or a tree structure and then

```
for( var i=0; i<scene.length; i++ ) {
    scene[i].checkCollision( player );
}
```

if you add a function `.checkCollision()` to every object, you can handle any special case in there.

It's a good idea to make the player a rectangle so the checking code doesn't become too complex.

Make the collision-checking-rectangle of the player object slightly smaller than the actual sprite; that makes the life easier for your players.

Comment: Will it be okay to have a circular collider around the character, instead of a rectangle? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Any simple shape will be OK unless you want to write a complex polgon-polygon collision check :-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should always have your objects in arrays. This includes things like enemies, bullets and other such things. That way your game can create and destroy them at will.

You seem to be talking about the actual frequency of the collision checks, and not the collision check method. To that my advice would be to only run collision checks on a finite number of the objects. Try using a grid, and only checking for collisions with objects in the same grid block as the player.

Another thing that helps is to have plenty of "short cuts" inside the method itself. These are things that can be checked quickly and easily before any complex math is done. For example, you could check the distances between the two objects. If the objects are farther away than their farthest corner, you don't have to check for a collision.

There are plenty of these methods that you can utilize in your own unique combination.